# Скрипт для тестирования опросника

Tags: javascript, json

Такая проблема, есть структура опросника заходящая в JSON формате, после переводиться в массив объектов, где каждый объект это вопрос. Нужно написать скрипт-тест который бегает по опроснику и проверят все возможные варианты, и после отправляет результат где есть количество вариантов прохождения опроса. Подскажите как написать логику теста.

Пример опросника:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 'id1',
    question: 'What is your marital status?',
    answer1: {
      text: 'Single',
      next_question: 'id2.1'
    },
    answer2: {
      text: 'Married',
      next_question: 'id2.2'
    }
  },

  {
    id: 'id2.1',
    question: 'Are you planning on getting married next year?',
    answer1: {
      text: 'Yes',
      next_question: 'id2.1.1'
    },
    answer2: {
      text: 'No',
      next_question: 'id2.1.2'
    }
  },

  {
    id: 'id2.2',
    question: 'How long have you been married?',
    answer1: {
      text: 'Less than a year',
      next_question: 'id2.2.1'
    },
    answer2: {
      text: 'More than a year',
      next_question: 'id2.2.2'
    }
  },

  {
    id: 'id2.2.2',
    question: '"Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?',
    answer1: {
      text: 'Yes',
      next_question: 'id2.2.2.1'
    },
    answer2: {
      text: 'No',
      next_question: 'id2.2.2.2'
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Что именно посчитать нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала преобразовываешь данные в структуру с которой удобно работать.

```
const tree = {};
for (const o of data) {
    tree[o.id] = [o.answer1.next_question, o.answer2.next_question];
}
```

После чего она будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
const tree = {
    "id1"    : [
        "id2.1",
        "id2.2"
    ],
    "id2.1"  : [
        "id2.1.1",
        "id2.1.2"
    ],
    "id2.2"  : [
        "id2.2.1",
        "id2.2.2"
    ],
    "id2.2.2": [
        "id2.2.2.1",
        "id2.2.2.2"
    ]
};
```

Остаётся только рекурсивно перебрать все варианты ответа.

```
const func = (q, h) => {
    h.push(q);
    for (const a of tree[q]) {
        if (!tree[a]) {
            console.log([...h, a]);
        } else {
            func(a, [...h]);
        }
    }
};

func(Object.keys(tree)[0], []);
```

Здесь нет проверки на бесконечный цикл вопросов, так что проверять это придётся отдельно.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 'id1',
    question: 'What is your marital status?',
    answer1: {
      text: 'Single',
      next_question: 'id2.1'
    },
    answer2: {
      text: 'Married',
      next_question: 'id2.2'
    }
  },

  {
    id: 'id2.1',
    question: 'Are you planning on getting married next year?',
    answer1: {
      text: 'Yes',
      next_question: 'id2.1.1'
    },
    answer2: {
      text: 'No',
      next_question: 'id2.1.2'
    }
  },

  {
    id: 'id2.2',
    question: 'How long have you been married?',
    answer1: {
      text: 'Less than a year',
      next_question: 'id2.2.1'
    },
    answer2: {
      text: 'More than a year',
      next_question: 'id2.2.2'
    }
  },

  {
    id: 'id2.2.2',
    question: '"Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?',
    answer1: {
      text: 'Yes',
      next_question: 'id2.2.2.1'
    },
    answer2: {
      text: 'No',
      next_question: 'id2.2.2.2'
    }
  }
];

let tree = {};
for (const o of data) {
  tree[o.id] = [o.answer1.next_question, o.answer2.next_question];
}

const func = (q, h) => {
  h.push(q);
  for (const a of tree[q]) {
    if (!tree[a]) {
      document.write(`<pre>${[...h,a].join(` -> `)}</pre>`);
    } else {
      func(a, [...h]);
    }
  }
};

func(Object.keys(tree)[0], []);
```